# Find list of groups where at least one member is part of list (rails, SQL)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have a simple has_many :through arrangement, as shown below

```
# employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :groups, through: :group_assignments
  # ...
end

# group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :employees, through: :group_assignments
  # ...
end

# group_assignment.rb
class GroupAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I have a list of employees.  For that list, I want to grab every group that contains at least one of the employees on that list.  How would I accomplish this in a manner that isn't horridly inefficient?  I'm newish to Rails and very new at SQL, and I'm pretty at a loss.  I'm using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production.

Comment: you mean "has_many :employees, through: :group_assignments" in group.rb..!!

Comment: yes, sorry about that. fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of employees named `employees_list`, this will work:

```
 Group.includes(:employees).where('employees.id' => employees_list.map(&:id))
```

This is roughly the kind of SQL you will get:

```
SELECT "groups"."id" AS t0_r0,
  "groups"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "groups"."updated_at" AS t0_r2,
  "employees"."id" AS t1_r0, "employees"."created_at" AS t1_r1, "employees"."updated_at" AS t1_r2
  FROM "groups"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "group_assignments" ON "group_assignments"."group_id" = "groups"."id"  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "employees" ON "employees"."id" = "group_assignments"."employee_id" 
  WHERE "employees"."id" IN (1, 3)
```

So what is happening is that `groups` and `group_assignments` tables are first being joined with a left outer join (matching the `group_id` column in the `group_assignments` table to the `id` column in the `groups` table), and then `employees` again with a left outer join (matching `employee_id` in the `group_assignments` table to the `id` column in the `employees` table).

Then after that we're selecting all rows where `'employees'.'id'` (the id of the employee) is in the array of employees in the employee list, which we get by mapping `employees_list` to their ids using `map`: `employees_list.map(&:id)`. The `map(&:id)` here is shorthand for: `map { |e| e.id }`.

Note that you could use `joins` instead of `includes` here, but then you would get duplicates if one employee is a member of multiple groups. Kind of subtle but useful thing to know.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: this is shorter, thanks.  can you explain what's going on in the where part?

Comment: awesome.  if you could just rename the employees list `employees_list` instead of `employees` to make things clearer, i'll accept the answer.

Comment: Done! Hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: cool.  so map(&:id) is actually returning an array of ids rather than an iterator over all the ids. got it! great answer.

Comment: would it be a whole different beast to order that returned list of groups based on how many listed employees are in the group? as in, if my list is [bob, alice], a group with both bob and alice would be in front of a group with just one of them.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on that, no time to answer just now.

Comment: You can do this in Rails by calling `sort { |g| (g.employees & employees_list).length }` to the result of the code above (so altogether: `Group.includes(:employees).where('employees.id' => employees_list.map(&:id)).sort { |g| (g.employees & employees_list).length }`). This will sort the resulting array by the length of the intersection between `employees_list` and the `employees` of each group. You might be able to do that directly in the DB (faster), I couldn't quite figure out how though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea, but depending on your data, you may need to select distinct.

```
Group.includes(:group_assignments => :employee).where(:employee => {:id => ?}, @employees.map(&:id))
```

Comment: this looks great, thanks so much.  a couple questions: 1) I'm assuming in `:group_assignments => :employee`, `:employee` is the id of the employee as stored in the group_assignments table? 2) map returns an iterator, right? So you can pass an iterator into that ? part? 3) what is the & in `&:id`? Sorry for the noobishness and thanks again for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Group.joins(:group_assignments).where("group_assignments.employee_id in (?)", @employees.map(&:id))
```